# Prove that $f$ is a surjection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f$:$\Bbb R^+ \times \Bbb R^+ \rightarrow \Bbb R^+ \times \Bbb R^+$ be defined by $f(x,y) = (\frac yx, xy)$.
Prove that $f$ is a surjection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}_+^2$. Then if we set 
$$\begin{cases}
a = \frac{y}{x} \\
b = xy
\end{cases}$$
Then it follows that $x = \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$ and $y = \sqrt{ab}$. Therefore, since the function is able to achieve every element within the codomain, we conclude it's surjective.

Comment: That is the solution in my book, yet I do not understand why it shows that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Since for every element in the codomain, I can provide you an element in the domain that maps to it, I have proven that the function can reach the entirety of the codomain. I recommend really understanding the definition of surjection before attempting more problems about it.

Comment: How does this solution show that for every element in the codomain, there is an element in the domain that maps to it? I think I understand what surjection is, but don't understand how this solution works.

Comment: The proof went, I took a random element in the codomain. I then used the fact that if such an element in the domain were to map to it, it would have to satisfy some system of conditions. When I solved that system, I realized a point (x,y) -> (a,b) under the function $f$. That realization proves f to be surjective since I'm guaranteed (x,y) lies in the domain.

Comment: why is it that this also gives the inverse (by replacing b by y and a by x)? I feel like I'm missing something

Comment: Because proving surjection is the same as identifying a right inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Choose arbitrary $(y_1,y_2)\in\mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R^+$. The system of equations:
\begin{align*}
&\frac{y}{x}=y_1\\
&xy=y_2
\end{align*}
has the solution $(x,y)=\left(\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{y_2}{y_1}},y_1\cdot\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{y_2}{y_1}}\right)\in \mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R^+$.
This imply that $f$ is a surjection.

Comment: This is essentially the same solution as that provided by gdepaul below. However, I do not understand how it shows that for every element in the codomain, there is an element in the domain that maps to it (which is the definition of a surjection).

Comment: Well, $(y_1,y_2)$ is an arbitrary element from codomain, and I shoved that $f\left(\left(\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{y_2}{y_1}},y_1\cdot\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{y_2}{y_1}}\right)\right)=(y_1,y_2)$.